# Configuring Ckan's authentication using Azure b2c OpenID Connect

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, openid, ckan

Im looking into configuring authentication for Azure B2C OIDC authentication on [Ckan](https://github.com/ckan/ckan) and was wondering if its possible to do so without modification to the code base or has anyone done it before..

I heard that it might be possible to install extensions for more features on Ckan but I am unsure which extension is for OpenID. I can't really find much documentation regarding this as well.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to install extensions to add more features on CKAN.

https://github.com/bcgov/ckanext-sso looks like the most updated extension  although the README says it's for CKAN 2.7 and it may need some work to be compatible with newer versions of CKAN.

https://github.com/keitaroinc/ckanext-saml2auth/ is a well maintained extension for SAML2 that can provide some guidance if you need to implement your own extension.

Documentation on how to build custom extensions for CKAN can be found at: https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/index.html

Bests!